# Convolution Reverb measurement request

Tags: adr, convolution, reverb

As someone has already done a request thread I feel a little better asking my own. I'm working on a live action show and I've suddenly been given ADR for a character in a single episode (nothing wrong with the original actor's performance but anyway). I've mixed it into the show as best I can.

However, it'd be nice to use a convolution reverb on the ADR (dry VO booth by the sounds of it) to sell it better. Sadly I live in Ireland and the show was shot on the Ben Kitay Studio in LA.

So, my question is this, does anyone already have a measurement for the stages there? If so can I be very cheeky and ask for a copy?

I was thinking that sound stages ought to have the files ready for post facilities to use as a standard part of the service. Wishful thinking? I know that sets being built will obviously change the acoustic and a lot of dialogue will be ADR'd. This particular show is all greenscreen and CG backgrounds and I was told that ADR wasn't being done from the start.

Ian

Comment: That sounds like a great selling point for a production sound mixer: _"We do the best we can to cleanly record the performance the first time. But sometimes issues beyond our control can force you to make the decision to go with ADR. So we capture and catalog impulse responses at every location to ensure the best sounding match between what's recorded by us and what's recorded later on the stage."_ I'd hire that guy.

Comment: Something tells me that many would agree.

Comment: I know I'll probably do that, now that I've read it. (Assuming I ever get over my fear of ADR.)

Comment: I've found ADR really challenging but it's a really satisfying experience when you hear the finished thing. As with most things it's best to respect something rather than fear it.